# Ubuntu install broken after adding a "Jessie" Debian repository

Tags: 12.04, debian

I was trying to build `pfff` to use `scheck` and a requirement for the compiler is version 4+ of `OCaml`. The versions available to my apt-get seem to indicate 3.12.1 and the build wasn't working.

Now I don't know what `Sid`, `Jessie` and the other names were but it said that version 4.0.1 was available but not stable if you add "Jessie". I assume that `Jessie` is a codename for unstable releases of GNU software or something?

I added this `deb http://ftp.nz.debian.org/debian jessie main` to my sources.list and ran `apt-get install ocaml` and voilà it found the new version.

I had a bit of a worry that it would try to update other dependencies and it did, but I let it run. One of the dependencies was `libc6` and before it finished it told me that my install was broken and the software could not fix itself.

Now I removed the entry from my sources.list and tried to run `apt-get install ocaml` again but it's complaining of all sorts of version problems, a program called `locales` is apparently causing a lot of strife and `libc6.1` too.

How do I remedy this?

I'm running 12.04 Precise Pangolin.

I have a feeling I'm misunderstanding something pretty fundamental about this whole thing. How do I install a Debian package on my Ubuntu system without having to screw everything else that's installed, up?

Comment: for 12.04 you should be messing with debian wheezy and not jessie